# How to cause a form to be submitted automatically on page load in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This may have an obvious answer, but I am very new to js so I have no idea how to do this. I would like a form on a page to be submitted automatically when that page is loaded without requiring any user action like pressing a button. How to do this?

Comment: May I ask you why you want to do that? It looks like there has to be a better solution than automatic submit.

Comment: Sometimes one wants to do things. Sometimes those things aren't common. This question was also helpful to me & ∄ another solution for my application. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<form id=lol action="file.php"></form>
<script>document.getElementById('lol').submit();</script>
```

Comment: this has the added advantage of submitting the form before the page loads :)

Comment: however the original question specifically asked for form submit on page load, not before page load

Answer (score 11):

Like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.formName.submit();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with what sAc suggests, but I'd use an event listener rather than just writing to window.onload:

```
function submit_form() { document.formName.submit(); }

if(window.attachEvent){
    window.attachEvent("onload", submit_form);
}else{
    window.addEventListener("load", submit_form, false);
}
```

Comment: why? Does it offer other benefits? (genuinely curious)

Comment: The biggest issue is that writing to window.onload will overwrite anything else assigned to window.onload.  Other than that, it has been considered an anti-pattern ever since a formal method for adding event listeners was added way back in the late 1990s.  The formal method for adding event listeners gives you the additional ability to inspect the event, and cancel any default action that may result from it (not usable for onload and unload though).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time to answer my question :)