# How to auto click an input button

Tags: javascript, html

I need the button with the ID of "clickButton" to be automatically clicked or "activated" just by someone loading the page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post"  action="http://web.com/">
<input type='hidden' value="test" id="chatbox" name='content' />

<!-- The Button -->
<input id="submitButton" class="button" name="accept" type="submit" value="Send"/>

</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What I have tried:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

//In here I would use several Javascript codes, 
//including all the ones I have been given 
//here

</script>


</head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post"  action="http://web.com/">
<input type='hidden' value="test" id="chatbox" name='content' />

<!-- The Button -->
<input id="submitButton" class="button" name="accept" type="submit" value="Send"/>

</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Also if I wanted a javascript code to repeat it self, what command would I use?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried; SO isn't some free service to write your code for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273154/how-to-cause-a-form-to-be-submitted-automatically-on-page-load-in-javascript

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I see what you really want to *auto submit* the form. This would do it:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.getElementById('clickButton');
    button.form.submit();
}
```

**EDIT**
If what you want is really auto submit the form automatically n times, each second, whis would do:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var button = document.getElementById('clickButton'),
    form = button.form;

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    return false;
  })

  var times = 100;   //Here put the number of times you want to auto submit
  (function submit(){
    if(times == 0) return;
    form.submit();
    times--;
    setTimeout(submit, 1000);   //Each second
  })(); 
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 17):

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('clickButton').click();
}
```

I try to make a habit of explaining my code, but I think this is pretty self-explanatory.  If you want it to repeat, just call the function that's set to the click listener of `clickButton`.  Unless you mean over and over, in which case use setInterval or setTimeout (less recommended).

Comment: I put the code within my page:                                  
             <head>  <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('clickButton').click();
}
</script>
</head>
             But nothing happened .-. any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I think clicking without being user triggered is not so good practice, you can achieve the same without needing to triggers click, but you can try this

```
window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.getElementById('clickButton');
    setInterval(function(){
        button.click();
    },1000);  // this will make it click again every 1000 miliseconds
};
```

Comment: This also did not work, could you give me an example on how I would add this to the page? I believe I'm doing it right, but it is always nice to double check

Comment: @user3186159 what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can directly send the form instead of clicking the button:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

But my best advice would be to let the user know what you are doing... users really don't like it when a wizard is playing with their page.

```
<label for="accept">Click here to continue</label>
```