# javascript autoclick does not seem to autoclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new to javascript and jquery and I'm trying to get a button to autoclick from an existing code base. I am having trouble getting the button to do that even though this is what I've been following [How to auto click an input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069232/how-to-auto-click-an-input-button).

The code is below. I've tried using both `.submit()` and `.click()` but the `start-game-btn` doesn't seem to get pressed either way. I've put a `console.log` within the button whenever it's pressed and the message doesn't seem to get logged.

```
console.log("loading...")

$(() => {

  $("#start-game-btn").click(event => {
    console.log("start-game")
    $("#errors").text("")
    event.preventDefault()
    const height = parseInt($("#height").val())
    const width = parseInt($("#width").val())
    const food = parseInt($("#food").val())
    let MaxTurnsToNextFoodSpawn = 0
    if ($("#food-spawn-chance").val()) {
      MaxTurnsToNextFoodSpawn = parseInt($("#food-spawn-chance").val())
    }
    const snakes = []

    $(".snake-group").each(function() {
      const url = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/"//$(".snake-url", $(this)).val()
      console.log(url)
      if (!url) {
        return
      }
      snakes.push({
        name: "M1",//$(".snake-name", $(this)).val(),
        url
      })
    })
    if (snakes.length === 0) {
      $("#errors").text("No snakes available")
    }
    console.log(12)
    fetch("http://localhost:3005/games", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        width,
        height,
        food,
        MaxTurnsToNextFoodSpawn,
        "snakes": snakes,
      })
    }).then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(json => {
        const id = json.ID
        fetch(`http://localhost:3005/games/${id}/start`, {
          method: "POST"
        }).then(_ => {
          $("#board").attr("src", `http://localhost:3009?engine=http://localhost:3005&game=${id}`)
        }).catch(err => $("#errors").text(err))
      })
      .catch(err => $("#errors").text(err))
  })
  console.log("ready!")
})

window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.getElementById('start-game-btn');
    button.form.submit();
    console.log("Done!!")
}
```

Everytime I refresh the page the log shows:

```
loading...
ready!
Done!!
```

What I think it should be logging is (or at least that's what I'm trying to achieve):

```
loading...
start-game
ready!
Done!!
```

Comment: `$("#start-game-btn").click();`

Comment: I added a more detailed answer so it can be accepted and this question will be marked as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`submit()` does not work because it is for submitting forms.
`button.form.submit();` does not work because it assumes your button is part of a form.
As it looks like you are using jQuery, try just calling the [jQuery click function](https://api.jquery.com/click/) without any parameters using a jQuery selector.
eg.
`$("#start-game-btn").click();`