# Auto click the Start Recognition button

Tags: javascript, azure, api, speech-recognition

Please run this page https://113.193.25.22/python_project/js-browser/convert.html. This is a not a proper https page, so please forcibly run this page in https.

This page is not converting Speech to Text (using Microsoft Azure service). This page is working only if click on the button "Start Recognition". But when I try to auto click the button by using the code

**setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton").click(); }, 4000);**  I am getting the error  **The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.**

How to auto click this button?

I tried the code

**setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton").click(); }, 4000);**  but I am getting the error  **The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.**

Auto button click should work without manual click by the user

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Provide a complete and minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cause a form to be submitted automatically on page load in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273154/how-to-cause-a-form-to-be-submitted-automatically-on-page-load-in-javascript)